# where should i handle things like triggering notifications in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, notifications

From my understanding the objects in django rest framework have specific purposes

**Model:**
Representation of the data in a database

**Serializer:**
Converts models to json and requests to models (crud operations)

**View:**
External interface to the application. Accepting requests and returning the appropriate responses

If I want to trigger socket push notifications or do anything else that doesn't exactly fit into the three objects by the definition I gave, where would I put it?

Example:
Let's say there is an object `ChatMessage` and whenever it is created some data needs to be sent to a web socket to notify users. What is the appropriate place to handle that?

Comment: I usually go with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) (`post_save`), but triggering actions on a `perform_create` in the view would be a reasonable approach as well, for example.

Comment: I had initially worked with signals which seemed reasonably clean to me because it is decoupled from the general drf architecture and pluggable. I ran into issues however as I want to handle the change of multiple objects in one operation but received post_save events for all of them and had trouble finding out what exactly changed

Comment: You could have a tasks.py where you implement add the logic of sending out the push notifications. Basically, you can have any other arbitrary Python file in your project with some other custom logic. The API is not the only part of your project so you're not constrained to the models, views and serializers

Comment: I would still need to trigger these events from somewhere, right? And as @henriquesalvaro suggested this would need to be either with signals or inside any of the framework classes

Comment: You can define your own signals if `post_save` isn't the right one for you. You can pass any python object into the signal, also a list of objects. It's hard to answer much more precisely what should send/trigger the signal, but if something is happening in your view, that's the place to send the signal. Also model methods are a good place to send signals. For example, I have a Transaction model that sends a custom signal when its status is changed.

Comment: Careful with signals - from my experience, they become unmanageable when the project grows to some serious size. But maybe it is just me :)